# Rename all files in directory using bash by decrementing filename by 1

Tags: bash, shell

Is there a way to rename a directory full of files named with the following convention, without using regex? For instance, I have files named `1.json`, `2.json`, `3.json`, `4.json` and I want them all renamed to their current `#{NUM}` to `#{NUM - 1}` so the result set would be: `0.json`, `1.json`, `2.json`, `3.json`.

Using the convention:

```
for i in *.json; do mv -- "$i" ..
```

Is it possible to do this without regex? Or am I stuck parsing for the file name, converting a string to integer and going from there?

Comment: you only show filenames with single digits, could you also have filenames with 2-, 3-, more-? digits?

Comment: @markp-fuso yeah and I just saw your comment below to see why this is relevant. I just omitted them for brevity but see the problem in doing so.

Answer (score 5):

`${var%suffix}` will remove a trailing suffix. You can use it to strip off `.json` and get just the numbers.

```
for file in *.json; do
    i="${file%.json}"
    echo mv -- "$i".json "$((i-1))".json
done
```

Remove the `echo` if it looks good.

---

Note that this will only handle single digit file names. To handle multi-digit file names we need to have them sorted *naturally* rather than *lexicographically*. Lexicographic sorting puts `10` before `9` since the character `1` is less than `9`, meaning `10.json` will get renamed to `9.json` before `9.json` is renamed to `8.json`. Natural sorting, by contrast, will sort `9` before `10`.

Sadly, this makes the whole thing ten times more cryptic. Globs can't be sorted inline so we have to move things around so that we can pipe the list of file names to `sort -g`. Then to loop over a stream of file names we have to change from a `for` loop to a [`while read` loop with process substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9784/how-can-i-read-line-by-line-from-a-variable-in-bash).

The basic skeleton structure looks like this:

```
while read file; do
    ...
done < <(ls *.json | sort -g)
```

Then we'll layer on a few improvements:

1. Use [`while IFS= read -r`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209123/understanding-ifs-read-r-line) to make the parsing more robust.
2. Avoid [parsing `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) by switching to a `printf`-based technique to print the file names.
3. Use NUL separators instead of newlines, since newlines are technically legal characters in file names. That means adding `\0` to `printf`, `-z` to `sort`, and `-d $'\0'` to `read` to get each of the three to emit and consume NULs.

These steps are good general habits, but I'll admit they're not terribly important for this particular script, and they make the code look like Frankenstein's monster. I'm showing them here for pedagogical purposes. I won't tell if you remove them from your one-off personal use script.

Final, robust solution:

```
while IFS= read -rd $'\0' file; do
    i="${file%.json}"
    echo mv -- "$i".json "$((i-1))".json
done < <(printf '%s\0' *.json | sort -zg)
```

Comment: still possibility of overwriting if filenames like "011,json" and "11.json" exist. Also, you'll get errors if you try to do `$((i-1))` when i is `082" or somesuch.  ;-)

Comment: This will handle invalid octal numbers, and output the new number with the same zero padding as the original: `wid=${#i}; new=$(printf "%0*d.json" "$wid" $((10#$i - 1)) ); mv -- "$f" "$new"` -- although it will rename "1000.json" to "0999.json" (an additional `if` would be needed)

Answer (score 2):

You may use this `awk` based solution:

```sh
printf '%s\n' [1-9]*.json | sort -n | 
awk -F. '{print "mv", $0, ($1-1 FS $2)}' | bash

mv 1.json 0.json
mv 2.json 1.json
mv 3.json 2.json
mv 4.json 3.json
mv 5.json 4.json
```

Once you're happy with the output you can remove `echo` before `mv`.

Answer (score -1):

try this code. simpy by -1 from filename.
but if your filename contains zero at first name, lets say `001.json` ..n then there is `1.json` , this code will not work. because it will replace the current `1.json` file

```
declare -i newName=0
for i in `ls | sort -n | grep ".json"`
do
  newName=${i%%.*}-1
  mv -- "$i" "$newName.json"
done
```

Comment: at for i think you can do sort by change to this 
for i in `ls | sort -n | grep ".json"`

Comment: this fails for a filename like `082.json`. also overwriting is still possible if filenames like "011.json" and "11.json" exist together.

Comment: Please note: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)